# If all elements match requirement not using "if all"

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am learning python with a book: The exercise is to make a program that print True if all numbers in a list all odds.

I get it whit this approach

```
if all(x % 2 == 1 for x in list):
```

But the 'if all' approach is not yet explained. They only use while, if,for and booleans in the examples. Furthermore, seems to be a reflexive exercise about it is possible to do it, maybe not. It is possible to do it using the basic tools of above?

Comment: `all` is just a function in Python, and it can be easily implemented with `for`. You might consider trying to write `all` yourself as a good programming exercise.

Comment: Just read the docs for [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

The Python code you wrote is very idiomatic, keep up that good work.

To see how to do it differently, you can look at programming languages that are less advanced, such as C. That is a very basic programming language which lacks the features for this `if all` statement. Searching for "c all elements array true" should give you the code you are looking for. For such a simple piece of code, it's easy to translate the code back into Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

> all(iterable) .
>   Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

So `if all(x % 2 == 1 for x in li):` roughly translates to

```
def are_all_odds(num_list):

    #Flag to keep track if we encounter an even number
    flag = True
    for num in num_list:
        #Once we encounter a even number, we break the for loop
        if num % 2 != 1:
            flag = False
            break

    #Return the flag
    return flag
```

We can test this function by doing

```
print(are_all_odds([1, 2, 3, 4]))
#False
print(are_all_odds([1, 3, 5]))
#True
```

Also just a suggestion, `list` is a python builtin keyword, so don't use it in variables :)